# What is the proper way to handle a connection closed by a remote host?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have a service that accepts a HTTP request and processes some long taking task. Sometimes remote client can close the connection before the task completes, e.g.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  let connectionClosed = false;

  req.on('close', () => {
    connectionClosed = true;
  });

  while (true) {
    if (connectionClosed) {
      // What to do here?
      // Do I simply return?
      return;
    }

    // Whatever business logic
  }
});
```

Is there any response that the application need to produce in this case? Do I need to call `res.end()` or can I simply `return void` (like in the example)?

I just want to make sure that doing this is not going to result in a memory leak.

Comment: You *never* use a `while(true)` loop in node.js (unless there's an `await` or `yield` in the body)

Comment: Which is the case here, where the `// Whatever business logic` resides. Irrelevant to the question.